# How do I place an Input Validation code in RainFall?

Tags: java, arrays

We must create a RainFall class which has the following:
*An array an array of doubles that stores the rainfall for each of the 12 months of the year.

- a method which returns the Total Rainfall for the year.
- a method which returns the Average Rainfall for the year.
- a method which returns the month with the most rainfall.
- a method which returns the month with the least rainfall.
  *Demonstrate the class in a program that takes 12 doubles from the user ( In order from January - December). Do Input Validation; if your input is negative then ignore until you have 12 non-negative double.
- Once the user has given you all 12 doubles, create an instance of the RainFallclass and call its methods, printing out the total rainfall, the average monthly rainfall, the month with the most rain, and the month with the least rain, each on a separate line.

I had different codes earlier though I changed some things. I'm not sure if I'm able to merge these two together though I will try. How should i print the expected out the program is asking for?

`Main Source:

```
 public class Rainfall {
double [] rainfallStats;

public double getTotalRainfall(){
double totalRainfall;

for ( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ){
totalRainfall = totalRainfall + rainfallStats[ index ];
}
return totalRainfall;
}

public double getAverageRainfall()
{
    return getTotalRainfall() / rainfallStats.length;
}

public int getMostRainMonth() {
double mostRain = rainfallStats [0];
int mostRainMonth = 1;
for ( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ){
if ( rainfallStats[ index ] > mostRain) {
mostRain = rainfallStats[ index ];
mostRainMonth = index + 1;
}
}
return mostRainMonth;
}
public int getLeastRainMonth() {
double leastRain = rainfallStats [0];
int leastRainMonth = 1;
for ( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ){
if ( rainfallStats[ index ] < leastRain) {
leastRain = rainfallStats[ index ];
leastRainMonth = getMostRainMonth();
}
}
return leastRainMonth;
}
public Rainfall(double [] rainfallStatsGiven ){
rainfallStats = new double [ rainfallStatsGiven.length ];
for ( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ){
rainfallStats[ index ] = rainfallStatsGiven[ index ];
}
}
}
Input Validation:



 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class RainFallTest {

public static void fillArrayWitheUserDetails( double [] arrayGiven ){
String userInputString;
double userMonthlyRainfallFigure;
for ( int index = 0; index < arrayGiven.length; index++ ){
JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter rainfall figures for month " + ( index + 1 ));
userMonthlyRainfallFigure = Double.parseDouble( userInputString );
arrayGiven[ index ] = userMonthlyRainfallFigure;
}

}
public static void main( String[] args ) {

final int MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12; 
double [] rainfallStats = new double[MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR];
userOutputString;

fillArrayWithUserDetails( rainfallStats );

Rainfall rainfallData = new Rainfall ( rainfalStats );

userOutputString = String.format( "Total Rainfall: %.2f\nAverage monthly rainfall"+
":.2%f\nMonth with most rain: %d\nMonth with least rain: %d", 
rainfallData.getTotalRainfall(), 
rainfallData.getAverageRainfall(),
rainfallData.getMostRainMonth(),
rainfallData.getLeastRainMonth());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, userOutputString );
}
System.exit( 0 );
}


}
```

I don't get the expected out and barely any numbers. This link leads to a screenshot which I took. 
https://puu.sh/DaxHU/71f70c6c05.png

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Where is that Input Validation code at? Is it in another class somewhere?

Comment: I tried entering all this in a class, and it seems you are missing some methods, such as 'getLeastRainMonth()' so I don't think you provided all the code for this. Also , what is that System.exit(0) referring to, is this a cmd line app or something else?

Comment: public int getLeastRainMonth() {
double leastRain = rainfallStats [0];
int leastRainMonth = 1;
for ( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ){
if ( rainfallStats[ index ] < leastRain) {
leastRain = rainfallStats[ index ];
leastRainMonth = getMostRainMonth();
}
}
return leastRainMonth;
}
public Rainfall(double [] rainfallStatsGiven ){
rainfallStats = new double [ rainfallStatsGiven.length ];
for ( int index = 0; index < rainfallStats.length; index++ ){
rainfallStats[ index ] = rainfallStatsGiven[ index ];
}
}
}   // This is the Least Method

Comment: I have the input validation in the post. It's right under "Input Validation".

Comment: No. It's just something to stop the programming if it keeps going on. I updated the question. Everything is there.

Comment: https://puu.sh/DaCYH/3bdbc738f2.png The link is a picture of the expected output.